# Rearrange json with sample data

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, node-modules

Original json data:

```
{
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": ""
  "Implementations": [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"              
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"       
      },

      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",          
          "Name": ABCD
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": EFGH
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": IJKL        
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {          
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {      
      "Type": "Negative" 
    }  
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",  
  "CommonTwo": "",  
  "EatingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Fast"    
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {   
  },
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""
}
```

Expected json data:

```
{ 
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": ""
  "Implementations":    [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"         
         "Country": [
                {
                  "Orientation": "Male",          
                  "Name": ABCD
                }
            ],
              "State": [
                {          
                  "Address": "XYZ Street",
                  "ZipCode": "US"
                }
            ]

      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"          
        "Country": [
                {
                  "Orientation": "Female",
                  "Name": EFGH
                },
                {
                  "Orientation": "Female",
                  "Name": IJKL        
                }
              ],
        "State": [
                {          
                  "Address": "XYZ Street",
                  "ZipCode": "US"
                }
            ]
        }
    }
  ],
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {      
      "Type": "Negative" 
    }  
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",  
  "CommonTwo": "",  
  "EatingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Fast"    
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {   
  },
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""

}
```

Program:

```
//Original JSON data in question.
var Implementations = {
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": ""
  "Implementations": [
    {      
      "Male": {
        "Gender": "Male"              
      },
      "Female": {
        "Gender": "Female"       
      },

      "Country": [
        {
          "Orientation": "Male",          
          "Name": ABCD
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": EFGH
        },
        {
          "Orientation": "Female",
          "Name": IJKL        
        }
      ],
      "State": [
        {          
          "Address": "XYZ Street",
          "ZipCode": "US"
        }
      ]
    }
  ],
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {      
      "Type": "Negative" 
    }  
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",  
  "CommonTwo": "",  
  "EatingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {    
    "Type": "Fast"    
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {   
  },
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""
}

// Program that make the conversion
var finalResult = [];
for (var i=0; i<Implementations.Implementations.length; i++) {
  var currentImplementation = Implementations.Implementations[i];
  var targetObj = {
    "Male": {
      "Gender": "Male",
      "Country": [],
      "State": currentImplementation.State
    },
    "Female": {
      "Gender": "Female",
      "Country": [],
      "State": currentImplementation.State
    }
  };
  for (var j=0; j<currentImplementation.Country.length; j++) {
    var currentCountry = currentImplementation.Country[j];
    if (currentCountry.Orientation === 'Male') {
      targetObj.Male.Country.push(currentCountry);
    } else if (currentCountry.Orientation === 'Female') {
      targetObj.Female.Country.push(currentCountry);
    }
  }
  finalResult.push(targetObj);
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(finalResult));
```

How do I add the objects like Personality Traits, Eating Habits, Reading Habits, Fitness Habits and attributes like Universal and common outside of the Implementations object as shown in the expected json data?

Comment: Please post the expected result as well. What do you want the object to rearrange into?

Comment: I have made edits to make it clear.Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be using `Object.assign` to merge the attributes.

```
//The Original Data
const Implementations = {
  "Implementations": [
    {
      //Ignore 
    }
  ]
}
//The Attributes needed
const attributes = {
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": "",
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Negative"
    }
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",
  "CommonTwo": "",
  "EatingHabits": {
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {
    "Type": "Fast"
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {
  },
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""
}

const newData = Object.assign({}, Implementations, attributes);
console.dir(newData);
```

OR just add the data inside.

```
const Implementations = {
  "Implementations": [
    {
      //Ignore 
    }
  ]
}

const newData = {
  "UniversalOne": "",
  "CommonOne": "",
  "PersonalityTraits": [
    {
      "Type": "Positive"
    },
    {
      "Type": "Negative"
    }
  ],
  "UniversalTwo": "",
  "CommonTwo": "",
  "EatingHabits": {
    "Type": "Excessive"
  },
  "ReadingHabits": {
    "Type": "Fast"
  },
  "FitnessHabits": {
  },
  "UniversalThree": "",
  "CommonThree": ""
}

newData.Implementations = Implementations.Implementations;
console.dir(newData);
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.Can you help edit the program without adding another variable and merging the two? I wanted to push the objects in question instead of merging.The current program does not address the objects like personalityTraits,eating,reading habits and also attributes like universal and common outside of the Implementations.

Comment: You have completely changed the question after the edit. Please ask a separate question maybe. Sorry will not edit my answer anymore.

Comment: okay I will add a separate question. Your solution still works if we have to merge two json objects.